# SQL: query contains at least one "true" value

Tags: sql

I have this tables:

```
TABLE path:

id  idT  nome  bool1
1   it1  pp    true
2   it1  ff    false
3   it1  ss    false
4   it2  rr    false
5   it3  ee    true
6   it3  zz    true
7   it4  xx    false
8   it4  yy    false
```

I want to get the following table:

```
idT nome  bool1
it1 pp    true
it1 ff    false
it1 ss    false
it3 ee    true
it3 zz    true
```

I tried with:

```
 select nome, bool1 from path where bool1='true';
```

But I get only the values ​​"true" and not as the second table that I posted!

I want you to give me back "idT" (with fields "nome" and "bool1"), the values ​​of "bool1" contain at least one "true".

Comment: This is isn't a place where you can just ask for your job to done by someone else. Make an effort and put an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `SELECT * FROM path` will give you what you have asked for, but I suspect that's not your intent. Please clarify your requirements (and show what you have already tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show some effort and try to solve it yourself (it's good for learning if for no other reason), but anyway, this can be done in several ways. This is two:

```
SELECT idt, nome, bool1 FROM path
WHERE idt IN (
  SELECT idt FROM path WHERE bool1 = 'true');

SELECT path.idt, nome, bool1 FROM path
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT idt FROM path WHERE bool1 = 'true') q ON path.idt = q.idt;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c03b8/5)